# LaTex Symbol Usage Statistics

Tags: data

Are there any available resources that contain data on LaTeX symbols usage metrics. I want to know what the most used symbols are to determine which I should account for in a project I'm working on.

Comment: [Scrape arXiv](https://github.com/Mahdisadjadi/arxivscraper) in LaTeX.

Comment: I'm not fully clear on what you're looking for. You could scrape arXiv, as @Emre suggests, but is there a specific symbol you're looking for?